# materializecss framework rails 4.2 integration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, css-frameworks

I found [this](http://materializecss.com) css framework, unfortunately, it lacks gem support like what Twitter bootstrap does.

So I downloaded their sass source and tried to integrate into rails asset pipeline albeit with errors.

```
Undefined variable: "$button-height".
  (in /app/assets/stylesheets/components/_buttons.scss:4)
```

Or should I put that into /lib folder?[image]

**My question is: How to install this framework with rails 4.2?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can youse `bower` or use this gem https://github.com/mkhairi/materialize-sass

I've had some issues with materialize fonts using bower, I suggest use the gem =)

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution adding the gem into the Gemfile

just do:

```
gem 'materialize-sass'
```

and update the Gems, search in to your assets/stylesheets the applications.css if you have the ".css" extension you need rename it to **applications.scss** and finally add this import **@import "materialize";**

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.scss, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
 @import "materialize";
```

:)